# Attempting to get a count of records from gridview based on a selected date from dropdownlist but cant?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

The problem lies that upon selection of the date in the dropdown it will give the count of the LAST selection, not the current.
I am a novice and the only thing I can think of is some type of postback issue? The gridview populates fine with the records selected by the DDL, so I just cant get my head around why the count that is rendered is the previous selection.

```
protected void ddlClassDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        lblRecordCounter.Text = "";
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand comm;
        SqlDataReader reader;

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gescdb"].ConnectionString;

        conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT (*) FROM gescdb" +
            "WHERE ClassDate=" + ddlClassDate.Text, conn);

        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            reader = comm.ExecuteReader();                
            GridRegistrants.DataSource = reader;
            GridRegistrants.DataBind();                
            reader.Close();
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        finally
        {              
            conn.Close();
            lblRecordCounter.Text = GridRegistrants.Rows.Count.ToString();

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `Page_Load` method you do the same, right? You have to move that code into following block:

```
if (!IsPostBack){
    //Your code is here
}
```

Comment: Yes,  What happens is On Page Load the label will have a count of 0 which is correct, when you select a date from the DDL, the grid populates but the count remains at 0, then when you make a second selection from the DDL, the grid populates with the correct info BUT the count is from the previous selection.  ??

Comment: You have to increase your *count* before population. Or if you use *count++*, change it to *++count*

Comment: Post your page_load also

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            GridRegistrants.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }

Comment: Khazratbek can you elaborate?  Thanks

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper On the first load you have to bind your gridview, and then on index changing bind it again, in that case you will not have problems

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper I will post it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Your DropDownList:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlClassDate" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlClassDate_SelectedIndexChanged" />
```

Your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){
    if (!IsPostBack){
        BindDDL();
        BindGrid(ddlClassDate.SelectedValue);
    }
}

protected void BindDDL(){
    //Bind Your dropdownlist here
}

protected void BindGrid(string ddate){
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gescdb"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from gescdb where ClassDate = @date", conn);
    comm.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = ddate;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sda.Fill(ds);                
        GridRegistrants.DataSource = ds;
        GridRegistrants.DataBind();
    }
    catch
    {
        //...
    }
    finally
    {              
        conn.Close();
    }
}

protected void ddlClassDate_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e){
    BindGrid(ddlClassDate.SelectedValue);
}
```

Comment: I am using sqldatasourse to fill my ddl with dates.  not using static items

Comment: I am getting error "Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'GridRegistrants'.  Remove one definition."  I have the DDL fill using the sqlDataSource on the control "" <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource3" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:gescdb %>" 
                SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [ClassDate] FROM [gescdb]">  ...... So I did not apply the BindDDL() Routine,  but I am getting the above error 
            </asp:SqlDataSource>""

Comment: Khazratbek,  Thanks for your assistance.  After reviewing all of the code I found the issue on the Grid.  I removed the DataSourceID and it worked fine so far.  Now I am doing a little testing but appears to be fixed.  Again, Thank you

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper you are welcome. Accept any answer, your question will be solved and anybody with similar question might be able to see the possible solution

Comment: Khazratbek,  a problem I have found while testing is that the sort feature of the grid no longer works. I have tried to place an order by lastname asc on my sql select statement but the grid will not populate with any data. The grid works great as far as selecting the info by the date in the dropdownlist but I need to be able to sort the data by lastname as well. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper what is the structure of your table?

Comment: I have the id lastname firstname skill level and enrollment date displayed in the grid. Since the changes above I cannot get the grids built in sort feature to work.  I have even tried doing an Order by lastname in the sql statement and it will not work.  Any ideas?

Comment: *select * from gescdb where enrollmentDate = @date order by lastname* exactly will work

Comment: Thanks.  I was placing my ORDER BY in front of my WHERE statement lol

Comment: @NoviceDeveloper it was your mistake :)